# Why do I have to press back to get back to my main activity?

Tags: java, fragment, parent, back

I'm having an issue developing an android app, what is happening is that when I try to press the back button from in my fragment view, It appears to close to an exact copy of the same fragment. If I press back again it then goes to my main activity(which I want to happen the first time the button is pressed)?

Here's my window that calls the fragment

```
    public class DaysWindow extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_days_window);
        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(message);
        scan.useDelimiter(";");

        if(savedInstanceState==null){



            DaysFragment days = new DaysFragment();
            days.setArguments(intent.getExtras());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, days).commit();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.days_window, menu);
    return true;
}

    }
```

And here's the fragment I'm seeing twice

```
    public class DaysFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
String days;
String message;


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup Container, Bundle       SavedInstanceState){

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_days, Container, false);
    days=getArguments().getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    TextView textView= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.DaysTextView);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(days);
    scan.useDelimiter(";");
    textView.setText(scan.next());


    return view;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Does your layout file for `activity_days_window` also have the fragment?